# Convert text to numeral text

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumproduct

I have a google spreadsheet that I am using as a quiz. The quiz takers select an option from a data validation drop down.

The cell below strips all but the first character `=left(A2,1)` which is a numeral value. Further below in the sheet is a cell that sums certain cells, For instance,

```
=Sum(A3,D3)
```

[image: Example]

For some reason, the sum function does not recognize the cell as a purely numeral value, even with changing the format to number. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `value()` to convert a string to number. So `value(left(A2,1))`

Comment: Off-topic but I suppose you want Sum(A3:D3)

Comment: `=left(a2,1)*1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `SUMPRODUCT` instead of `SUM` which is able to recognize numeric values even if they are disguised as a text string:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A3:D3)
```

another way would be use regex like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRAXT(A3:D3, "(\d+)-")*1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given what is immediately above the values in Row3, that row might be redundant and the total calculated as:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(0+left(A2:D2)))
```